# Identity Server validate user using API

Tags: c#, identityserver4

is it possible to make the identityserver to validate the user using External API instead of the In Memory users or database .

basically once a user authenticate , my Idsv will try to validate the user using an External API

Comment: Do you mean using another user store (like a database) or actually using another API with some authentication method, because that would defeat the purpose of having ID Server in the first place.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Yes Exactly and i know but i want to make identity Server use an authentication Method which calls external api

Comment: If that external api is an identity provider then there are in built support for using those - there should be sample solutions on how to use Google/Facebook authentication with Identity Server for example.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius No , its a custom api which has no ids provider

Comment: No easy way then as it defeats the purpose if having Identity Server as the authority service in the first place.